# How to pass a condition in read_delim() function argument?

Tags: r

I would like to use the function `read_delim()` from {readr} only once and to pass in the argument `col_select` a condition with an if.

If "param==all" then all columns are read
Otherwise only the columns filled in `columns` object are read.

```
library(readr)

param <- "all"
columns <- "mpg"

verif <- read_delim(file = readr_example("mtcars.csv"),
                    col_select = if (param=="all") NULL else all_of(columns))
```

With "all" case, I'll get this issue :

```
Error in UseMethod("collector_value") :                                                                                                    
  no applicable method for 'collector_value' applied to an object of class "c('collector_skip', 'collector')"
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: The tidy evaluation is wreaking havoc on S4 dispatch somewhere down the stack. When in the tidyverse, do as the tidies do:  tidyselect `everything()` as suggested by @langtan or the unquote (`!!`) as suggested by @akrun which can be inlined, also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `everything()` instead of NULL:

```
verif <- read_delim(
  file = readr_example("mtcars.csv"),
  col_select = if (param=="all") everything() else all_of(columns)
)
```